# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am having "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error on chrome.

```
<?
$data = "this is description
         new line";
?>

$(".gantt").gantt({
  desc: "<? echo $data; ?>"
});
```

the error is between "this is description" and "new line". Why I cant use enter there? Is there a way to awoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have (unescaped)  new lines in JavaScript strings.

You are outputting:

```
$(".gantt").gantt({
  desc: "this is description
         new line"
});
```

The new line after `description` isn't valid.

You need to `json_encode` your value (yes, `json_encode` works on plain strings too).

```
$(".gantt").gantt({
  desc: <? echo json_encode($data); ?>
});
```

Note that I removed the quotes.  `json_encode` will add quotes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be rendered on the client side as:

```
$(".gantt").gantt({
  desc: "this is description
         new line"
});
```

This isn't allowed because JavaScript doesn't support multiline strings (not like this, anyway). I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to have strings in your JavaScript spanning multiple lines, you could do something like this:

```
<?
$data = "this is description\
         new line";
?>
```

Or this:

```
<?
$data = "this is description\" +
        \"new line";
?>
```

Or even this:

```
<?
$data = "this is description\\
         new line";
?>
```

To understand the difference between these styles, look at the rendered source on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
desc: "<?= str_replace('\n', '\\n', $data); ?>",
...
```

Javascript will choke on the new-line, but you can "escape it" to avoid the issue.

Or, as Marc B mentioned, you can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
...
desc: <?= json_encode($data); ?>,
...
```

*And if you find `json_encode` outputs empty values, chances are you need to [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) your content.*

Comment: wrong. `<? echo json_encode($data) ?>` is FAR safer. fixing newlines is pointless if the error is due to an extra `"`.

Comment: @MarcB: Depends on contents, but I suppose `json_encode` is more practical in a lot of ways.